# Can't load page while dev-console is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Today i encountered a problem using chrome.
Everything worked fine yesterday, no new plugins or anything installed, chrome is still the same version.

Whenever I have the dev-tools open and try to reload the page, chrome tells me, it can't get a connection. The console also drops this warning:

```
/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
```

I already searched for this, but couldn't find any help. Hope you can help me with this problem. Never had any problems like this before.

Comment: Tried running Chrome with all your extensions disabled?

Comment: Only had one extension installed. Disabled it. Still the same problem.

Comment: Can you precise what's displayed in Chrome, when you say: *"chrome tells me, it can't get a connection"*. Is `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` displayed on screen?

Comment: You've throttling turned on. make it _no throttling_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the description, it appears that you have *Network throttling* setted up as ***Offline*** in DevTools. See in the *Network Panel*, by default it should be on  *No throttling*:

[image]

Comment: Oh god...thanks. Must have activated it and forgotten to disable it again. Was the last thing i was thinking about.